# how to use flutter adyen payment getway?

Tags: flutter

```
  try {
  dropInResponse = await FlutterAdyen.choosePaymentMethod(
      paymentMethodsPayload: _paymentMethod.toString(),
      merchantAccount: merchantAccount,
      publicKey: pubKey,
      amount: 12.0,
      currency: 'EUR',
      iosReturnUrl: scheme,
      reference: ref,
      shopperReference: userID,
      allow3DS2: true,
      testEnvironment: true,
      storePaymentMethod: true,
      shopperInteraction: ShopperInteraction.ContAuth,
      recurringProcessingModel: RecurringProcessingModels.CardOnFile);
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  dropInResponse = 'PlatformException. ${e.message}';
} on Exception {
  dropInResponse = 'Exception.';
}
```

I am getting dropIn response successfully, but than what need to do any one can help me.

Comment: Can you add links to the package that you are using?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_adyen this should be it